# Django and orbited HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, django, comet, orbited

I'm attempting to get Django to play with orbited to achieve comet functionality. I'm  using pyorbited and following [this tutotial](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-and-comet/), which is admittedly 4 years

Upon calling `event` method of class `pyorbited.simple.Client` I recieve `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

I don't think the orbited server is getting the message from python: I'm running orbited non-daemonised and give full debug info and there is no indication the event was received.

My orbited configs are below. I'm wondering if there is a problem in these?:

```
[global]
proxy.enabled = 1
proxy.keepalive = 0

[access]
/chat -> localhost:9000

[listen]
http://:9000
```

Could it be a problem with the [[access]] mapping which I understand it to mean 'sending stuff to /chat results in passing on to localhost:9000 (aka orbited)'?